# Cannot start emulator on Mac OS X

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, android-emulator, macos

I'm using MAC M.L & Eclipse 4.2.2 ADT
I've installed Eclipse on MAC OS X

**I can't create Virtual Device (AVD)**

- Android SDK Manager error is Failed to run the Android SDK manager.Check the Android console view for details.
- Getting error like Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
  Error executing aapt: `Cannot run program "/Developer/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt": error=13, Permission denied: error=13, Permission denied  adsa        line 1  Android ADT Problem`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I've reffered Official Links
[Android setting up ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html),
[Managing AVD's with AVD Manager][2]

See screenshot of Errors [Click here](http://iosandmacbuddy.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/android-sdk-manager-error/)

Comment: are you trying to start an emulator or are you trying to download the SDK?

Comment: I was trying to start emulator..

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Nope not yet..why john?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it looks like you are not trying to run it properly. First things first you need to create an Android Virtual Device (AVD). This will be the profile of the device you will be emulating. Open up a terminal and follow these steps. Make sure you have the SDK installed and you are in the `./tools` directory of your SDK.

For this example I will be creating an AVD named "Nexus_7".

**Step 1: determine your target:**

```
/.android list targets
```

You will get an output of all of your available targets, here is the one I will use:

```
id: 3 or "android-18"
     Name: Android 4.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 18
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
```

**Step 2: Create the AVD:**

```
./android create avd -n "Nexus_7" -t 3
```

For simplicity, when it prompts you to create custom hardware specs, just enter (or enter no then press enter).

You should get output like this:

```
Created AVD 'Nexus_7' based on Android 4.3, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.lcd.density=240
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=512
```

**Step 3: Launch the Emulator**

Here is the moment of truth:

```
./emulator -avd "Nexus_7"
```

[image: loading AVD]

It will take quite a while for the emulator to start, especially on the newer Android builds. You can screw around with hardware acceleration if you want it to move a bit faster. Also you should use Screenshots to speed up the boot time. I got all of the info from:

- [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html)

Comment: john.. could you just tell me that where should i install Android sdk on my Mac?

Comment: I m unable to get output as you written in step 1 :(
$ android ls target
-bash: android: command not found